# How do I print the actual error message in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to return any actual error message in an R function send it an email to notify the user however it only prints the custom message in the R argument. Is there any way to send the actual error message in the email?

Below is the dummy script I have written so far:

```
mailme <- function(message){
  #function to send email
}

b<-function(){
  r <- NULL
  attempt <- 1
  while( is.null(r) && attempt <= 3 ) {
    attempt <- attempt + 1
    try({
      x<-2+3
      prin(x)})
  }
  stop("The error message")
}

a <- tryCatch({
  b()
}, error = function(e){
  mailme(e$message)
})
```

The actual error message that is returned is

```
Error in prin(x) : could not find function "prin"
```

However the error message that I get in my email is

```
The error message  #from the stop used in function b
```

How do I call the actual error message inside the stop?

Answer (score 5):

I may be misunderstanding your question but I feel like you're complicating things unnecessarily with two `tryCatch`es. Why not just define your function and then call it from within a single `tryCatch`. A more simplified example:

```
# function that will always error
my_fun <- function() prin(x)

tryCatch({
    my_fun()
  }, error = function(e) {
    print(e$message) # replace with mailme(e$message)
})
# [1] "could not find function \"prin\""
```

Of course, replace `print` with `mailme` in your actual code.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your response, what I am trying to achieve is the function `my_fun()` in your example should itself retry one more time after failing before throwing the error message